# Cancel a published realease of android application in Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I just published the my v1.1 app, and I realized it crash on startup. Is it posible to revert the update I made in production in the play store???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your control panel, click the APK tab.

In the top right, click the `Switch to Advanced Mode` button.

Find the specific version that you would like, and activate it / move it to production.